# top 0 in carousel bootstrap 4 doesn't work

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I try to make teal rectangle move to top of carousel. I had give my carousel **position relative** and my teal rectangle **position absolute** and **top="0"**, but it doesn't work well. my teal rectangle always move to top of my browser. what did I miss?

```css
.rectangle1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.rectangle2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: teal;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

.rectangle3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.parent-carousel {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="rectangle1"></div>
<div class="rectangle3"></div>
<div class="parent-carousel">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1649825303952-84e1c9832cfd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559068285-4e4a5466e09a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1104&q=80" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rectangle2"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `div.rectangle2` inside of `div.parent-carousel` and also setting `z-index: 1` for it to remain visible.

The absolute positioned element is relative to its closest parent element with `position: relative` (or `<body>`).